# Формула в строку Java

Tags: java, строки, формулы

Задача: Составить таблицу значений функции y = f(x) на отрезке [n; m] с шагом k

Собственно вопрос возникает в моменте. Как ввести f(x). Ибо сама формула (для примера х-2), является строкой, а значение Y числом. 
т.е. Через сканер вводим все значения n,m,k и саму формулу "x-2" или любую другую. И в коде эту формулу применяем для подсчета значение Y.

```
while(x<=r.m){
        y=x-5;
        System.out.println("x = " +x+" y = "+ y);
        x=x+r.k;
}
```

В данном случае у меня стоит формула, введенная изначально "y=х-5" (вторая строчка, введено топорно, прямо в код), а мне надо, чтоб программа считала ту, которую я введу через сканер.

upd. После большого количества прочитанного и опробованного, хочется добавить, что введеное через сканер представляет собой цисловые значения, букву X и знаки арифметических вычислений ("+","-","/","*").

Comment: гляньте [тут](http://kostin.ws/java/java-input-stream.html)

Comment: стало лучше, но X захватывать пока не хочет. Но озарение близко.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение ленивого человека выглядит так:

```
import javax.script.*;

public class Eval
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        ScriptEngineManager engineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
        engine.put("x", 1);
        System.out.println(engine.eval("x * 2 + 1"));
    }
}
```

В Java есть полноценный [движок JavaScript](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html) ([на русском](https://habrahabr.ru/post/195870/)), который отлично справляется с вычислением произвольных математических выражений (и не только их).

Решение же человека, которому описанная задача прилетела в виде лабораторной работы или домашнего задания выглядит сложнее. Преподаватель, скорее всего, ожидает, что вы [разберёте](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7) вводимую строку на токены (переменная, оператор, число), переведёте её в [обратную польскую запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C), а затем вычислите, используя стековую машину ([раз](https://habrahabr.ru/post/100869/), [два](https://habrahabr.ru/post/282379/)).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) Задачка не от препода, а из этих ваших интернетов :)